# Problem when I send file to database firebase I get empty object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, axios

I post a request to the firebase from javascript by axios in this way :

```
var dataCanvas = canvas.toDataURL().replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");

let file;
let config = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  },
};

const linkSource = `data:image/png;base64,${dataCanvas}`;
await fetch(linkSource)
  .then((res) => res.blob())
  .then((blob) => {
    file = new File([blob], "test", {
      type: "image/png"
    });

    console.log('file is founded', file);
    axios.post(
        "https://DB.firebaseio.com/screens.json",
        JSON.stringify({
          image: JSON.stringify(file)
        }),
        config

      )
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log('response    ', response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // console.log(error);
      });
  });
```

But I get an image key as an empty object in firebase.

And this is the object file :

File {name: 'test', lastModified: 1671521367250, lastModifiedDate: Tue Dec 20 2022 11:29:27 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 128534, …} lastModified : 1671521367250 lastModifiedDate : Tue Dec 20 2022 11:29:27 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time) {} name : "test" size : 128534 type : "image/png" webkitRelativePath : "" [[Prototype]] : File

Comment: How is `file` initialized? Or even better: can you reproduce with a hard-coded value and show us that code, and its output?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen , I put the code as an answer below.

Comment: Please don't post additional information as an answer. Instead, click the `edit` link under your question and provide the information in the question itself.

Comment: Okay, I did that, sorry. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Any reason you're using the REST API instead of one of the JS SDKs? Also, I don't think you can store binaries in the RTDB. For that you should use Cloud Storage

Comment: If your `image` property shows up with an empty value in the database, log `JSON.stringify(file)` as that likely outputs that empty value. If you want to get the base64 bytes, have a look at https://pqina.nl/blog/convert-a-file-to-a-base64-string-with-javascript/ although you might also be able to just write `linkSource`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing a few too many data conversions in your code and then end up trying to write the `JSON.stringify` of a `File` object to the database, which seems to end up as an empty string.

If I recall correctly, the Firebase Realtime Database's [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data) doesn't require a `content-type` header, but if you *do* pass one it has to be `application/json`.

So with those two: if you want to store the base64 encoded string value of the data in your canvas, you can do:

```
axios.post(
  "https://DB.firebaseio.com/screens.json",
  JSON.stringify({
    image: canvas.toDataURL()
  }),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
)
```

As Mike commented, consider using a Firebase SDK for your platform as that'll make it much easier to interact with the database.

He also explained more about Axios, and it seems this should work too:

```
axios.post(
  "https://DB.firebaseio.com/screens.json", {
    image: canvas.toDataURL()
  }
)
```

Comment: The headers in OP's `config` object are incorrect for the payload

Comment: Good catch Phil!

Comment: You could just as simply omit `JSON.stringify()` and the custom header and let Axios work it out. If you have to tell it to do everything, you might as well just use `fetch()` 

Comment: I'm not an Axios user, so... that might explain. :) --- But Firebase's REST API expects a JSON-encoded string (so with quotes). Will Axios do that?

Comment: Yep. If it sees a JS object it will stringify it and set the content-type header appropriately

Comment: Awesome! I added a simplified example in that case. Let me know if you spot any problems with it still.

Comment: Thanks, @FrankvanPuffelen, I already can save the file as base64 but I want to save it as a file, Therefore I used fetch to convert the base64 to a file and I tried it with PHP laravel API, It was good, but in firebase saved as empty.

Comment: Did you try what value `canvas.toDataURL()` returns in that case? In the simplified code in my answer, that is pretty much all that is used - so if the value in the database is empty, it seems that `canvas.toDataURL()` returns an empty value.